# How to determine the current week in a Google Calendar sidebar gadget

Tags: url, google-calendar-api, google-gadget

I am writing a [Google Calendar sidebar gadget](https://code.google.com/p/time-tracker-tags/source/browse/time-tracker-tags.xml) to keep track of the total hours per event tag (as determined in details of the event i.e. "tags: work").

Users can change the current week, month, day they are viewing in the calendar and I want to be able to count up the hours pertaining to their current view.

I don't see anywhere in the [gadget API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/gadgets/sidebar/#calendar.getEventsResults) (or any other Google Calendar API) that allows gadgets to access the currently displayed view. I have noticed that the URL has an anchor tag that looks like

`g|week-2+23127+23137+23131`

which corresponds to viewing Monday Feb. 23, 2015 - Sunday March 1, 2015 in week mode.

I have also noticed the following relationships:

- `23127` is the first day in the view
- `23137` is the last day in the view
- `23131` is the day selected in the month view (on the left of the calendar)

If there is a way to get the currently displayed view using the API, that would be ideal but I would settle for parsing the anchor tag. Unfortunately I cannot decipher how the numbers work.

Comment: Do you have a URL to play around with? The `2313` part could be the weeks since a date (the Epoch is close, but I get 2349 weeks since Jan 1 1970 for today using http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=1&d1=1&y1=1970&m2=1&d2=10&y2=2015 as a reference)

Comment: I posted the anchor portion of the url above but a full url looks like ```https://www.google.com/calendar/render?pli=1#g|week-2+23084+23090+23090```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Google API

The currently displayed date range can be accessed using the following [call](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/gadgets/sidebar/#google.calendar.subscribeToDates):

> `google.calendar.subscribeToDates(function(d) {
>      // do something
>   });`

where d is a [Google date range](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/gadgets/sidebar/#calendar.time) `d.startTime` and `d.endTime` being the beginning and end.

### Numbers

The numbers in the URL do not correspond directly to epoch date and time. Rather, each year has 512 days associated with it and each month has 32 days. For example, February has 28 days regularly but every leap year it has 29. The calendar never has to adjust for this since it simply allots each month 32 days and comes out with a nice even number every time.

A careful examination of the date ranges displayed will also show you that if you subtract the number for December 31 from January 1 you get 130. Accounting for the beginning and the end (don't count December 31 and January 1) will give you 128.

`12 * 32 + 128 = 512` -- 12 months a year, 32 days a month and a 128 gap per year

Also, for some reason January 1, 1970 has the associated number of 33 so add that to your calculations when determining dates.

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't fit in the comments, but here's how the encoding works:

The encoding scheme makes it easy to find the day/month/year from the number.

Take **23131** which yields **Feb 27, 2015** (from the example in your question).

Divide by 512 and add 1970 (epoch) for the **year**.

> 23131 / 512 = 45.xxx => 45 + 1970 = **2015**.

Get the remainder of that division and divide by 32 to find the **month**.

> 23131 mod 512 = 91 / 32 = 2.xxx = **February**

Get the remainder of that division and it's the **day**.

> 91 mod 32 = **27**

Comment: That's awesome. I'm glad you figured it out! I won't need to calculate it myself since the API provides me with the date range but this is fascinating.

Comment: You figured most of it out @carpenter. When I saw the powers of 2 in your numbers I knew it was going to be this kind of scheme.